# alternative of list.FindIndex(x => x.UpperLimit >=lInput && x.LowerLimit <= lInput); in .net 2.0 framework

Tags: .net, list

I realized lamba is not supported by .net 2.0;
would like to know the alternative of following statement in .net 2.0

list.FindIndex(x => x.UpperLimit >= dblInput && x.LowerLimit <= dblInput);

Comment: Labmda is supported in c#3.0 compiler and above even in .net 2.0. In other words if you're using VS2008 or newer version you can use lambda.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I see no indication that equality would be appropriate here at all. I strongly suspect that `x` and the element type of `list` are different...

Comment: using vs2005 ,what is the altrnative

Comment: @user3458716: You should have stated that in your question. Why can't you use a more modern compiler?

Comment: @user3458716 Jon has a answer for you then.

Answer (score 1):

> I realized lamba is not supported by .net 2.0

That's not true. You can use lambda expressions to create delegates in .NET 2.0 with no problem. You need a C# 3 compiler (or later), that's all - it's a *compile-time* transformation which doesn't need framework or CLR support. You won't be able to get expression tree support without a separate library, but that's a different matter, and you don't need that for `List<T>.FindIndex`.

So long as you're building with a C# 3+ compiler, the code you've given should be fine.

If you're using a C# 2 compiler, you can use an anonymous method instead:

```
// Change the type of x appropriately. You haven't told us the type of list.
int index = list.FindIndex(delegate(Foo x) { 
    return x.UpperLimit >= dblInput && x.LowerLimit <= dblInput;
});
```

That's pretty horrible though, and I would *strongly* encourage you to use a more recent version of the C# compiler if you *possibly* can. The C# 3 compiler was released in November 2007... do you *really* need to use something older than that?

Comment: compiler is of a lower version.what is the alternative

Comment: @user3458716: Use a compiler which is less than 6 years old. Which version of the compiler *are* you using?

Comment: cant really use a newer version,shouldnt x be replaced.?it throws  an error

Comment: @user3458716: Sorry, was confused about which was the parameter. I've had to give it a type of `Foo` because you haven't given us much information in the question (hint hint). You still haven't said *why* you can't use a more recent compiler. You're missing out on very significant productivity enhancements, even when targeting .NET 2.

Comment: list contains structure

Comment: @user3458716 Do note that now VS2013 is available. Express edition you can get for free.

Comment: @user3458716: That doesn't give us any significant information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints before you ask your next question - we shouldn't have to extract relevant information out of you in this painful manner...